# Fraleigh Abstract Algebra 7th edition, chapter 8 omitted?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, reference-request

I'm studying Fraleigh Abstract Algebra seventh edition international version, and it seems that chapter 8(Groups in Topology. It talks about homology and simplicial complexes) is omitted. In which version of Fraleigh Algebra can I find the deleted chapter?

Comment: Why not try the non-international version, assuming this is an issue with the version itself and not just a printing error for your book. Of course, it would be worthwhile to pickup a different copy of the same book, in case it *is* just a printing error with your book.

Comment: He deleted this after the first few editions.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Where can I get the non-international version?

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok. I will search for earlier versions then.

Comment: My non-international 7th edition has the chapter.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/First-Course-Abstract-Algebra-7th/dp/0201763907